# Connect PHP to Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 7.2

Tags: php, linux, oracle, oracle12c

I have downloaded;
Oracle Linux 7.2
Oracle Database 12c for Linux
Oracle Instance Client for 12c
(All are of the same version)

What I was successful with;
Installing Oracle Linux on VMWare
Installing Oracle Database 12c

**I need to;

Install LAMP with the capability of connecting to Oracle Database.

Install Instant Client with the capability of connecting php to Oracle Database.

Install phpmyadmin

Please Help ...**

Comment: I believe, phpmyadmin only supports mysql and mariadb. And read this http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Comment: I need phpmyadmin for the mysql in LAMP
Other than that I use Dbeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are PHP RPMs (including one for the PHP OCI8 driver to connect to Oracle Database) at http://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html

You will need to install the 'Basic' package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html first (this requires a click-through so it can't be in a yum channel).  It sounds like you have done this.

There's a lot of useful info about PHP OCI8 in the back half of this free book: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html